# Using iOS transaction receipt response data to get product attributes server side

Tags: ios, receipt-validation

I'm currently using the data from `transaction.transactionReceipt` to validate IAP transactions server side.

Is there a way to get the `SKProduct` information from this receipt data server side? Right now, when validating the receipt, you can see the product ID that Apple uses and I'm wondering if you can somehow use that product ID on the server to get the `SKProduct` attributes for that ID.

Has anyone done that before?